# how to delay ajax respond for number of seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading some results via jQuery ajax in a div container.
I would like the results to be shown to the user after a 2 seconds delay

I'm using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $('#myform').slideToggle('#loading');
        $('#loginhandle').show("slow");
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var age = $("input#age").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&age=' + age ;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "results.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#loading').slideToggle('#results');
                $('#results').show("slow");
                $('#results').html(msg)
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Results shown at contianer

```
<div id='loading' style='display:none'>
Please wait for while
</div>

<div id='results' style='display:none'>
<div id='results' class='results'></div>
</div>
```

i made change on the code at this part

```
$('#loading').slideToggle('#results');
```

to

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loading').slideToggle('#results');
}, 2000);
```

but it only delays the loading container so results are shown while it saying 'please wait'
so how i can delay it?

Comment: You have to delay everything inside the success callback. But please format your code properly in the question!

Comment: can you not poll the request in php? sleep()?

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique, so either rename `#results` or remove the second id and use either `find()` or `children()` to access the `.results` element. And why on earth do you want to make the user wait **TWO** seconds? That's insane imho. Just ask yourself, would you like to wait? ;-)

Comment: So your success function is odd here in that you are, for example, showing then hiding then showing fadeIn on #results.  Can you explain in plain English what the animation sequence you are looking for is as far as hiding #loading, loading the html into #results and then displaying #results? Why do you have 2 divs with #results id?  This is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am misunderstanding but to delay everything just put all the success function code in your setTimeout function.

```
success: function(msg) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $('#loading').slideToggle('#results');
     $('#results').show("slow");
     $('#results').html(msg).hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {

     });}, 2000);      
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

All you'll have to do is modify your `success` callback:

```
success: function(msg) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#loading').slideToggle('#results');
        $('#results').show("slow");
        $('#results').html(msg).hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {

        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to achieve the wanted result you should change the code in

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#loading').slideToggle('#results');
   $('#results').show("slow");
   $('#results').html(msg)
}, 2000);
```

The reason is that setTimeout delays only the code include in the closure you pass as a parameter.